# Angular formatted articles

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to make one off articles with interactive elements. Without angular I would store the html, js and css in a database and load them when the url is called. I want to do this with angular but you can’t really serialize an angular component to a database. How should I approach this? Dynamically load and store components in the filesystem or just store the articles in s database the vanilla way or is there something else?

By article I mean for example a scientific article about Genes or something and it contains interactive graphs. Or an article about math that contains an "equation calculator".

Comment: by your definition, what's an article? I would interpret an article to be a single component, but with different internal content. So, i wouldn't need to have multiple components - i'd have one, ArticleComponent, and load the text of the component from the server. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean by 'article'?

Comment: For example a scientific article that has interactive info graphics related to the topic

Comment: i guess the question is, is each article a separate component because it has different styling, or is the styling relatively the same but the article content is different?